# How can I make this Node.js code more concise?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I need to make three network requests within one function and I have wrapped these three network requests into an asynchronous function that uses await-to-js to receive errors or responses. Is there any way to make this three ifs into one, but return an error message as soon as one of them has an error?

```
let [loginErr, loginRes] = await to(sa_login(req))
if (loginErr) {
  return ctx.sendError('400',loginErr);
}

let [infoErr,infoRes] = await to(sa_getUserInfo(loginRes))
if(infoErr) {
  return ctx.sendError('400',infoErr);
}

let [courseInfoErr,courseInfoRes] = await to(sa_getCourseInfo(loginRes));
if (courseInfoErr) {
  return ctx.sendError('400',courseInfoErr)
}
```

Comment: Why do your functions return 2-tuples `[error, result]` instead of rejecting the promise? If they just rejected, you could use `try/catch`.

Comment: `sa_getUserInfo` and `sa_getCourseInfo` both depend on the first request. So they're a good candidate for `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to drop that [`await-to-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js) that transforms promise rejections into error/result tuples here and just use the plain functions.

Once you've done that, you can just

```
try {
  const loginRes = await sa_login(req);
  const infoRes = await sa_getUserInfo(loginRes);
  const courseInfoRes = await sa_getCourseInfo(loginRes);
} catch (err) {
  return ctx.sendError("400", err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```js
try {
 const[loginErr,loginRes] = await to(sa_login(req));
 if(loginErr) throw loginErr;
 const [infoErr,infoRes] = await to(sa_getUserInfo(loginRes))
 if(infoErr) throw infoErr;
 const [courseInfoErr,courseInfoRes] = await to(sa_getCourseInfo(loginRes))if 
 if (courseInfoErr) throw courseInfoErr;
} catch(e) { return ctx.sendError('400', e); }
```

**This is not the best solution** and however you should re-throw your error in the `catch` statement and catch it on the top level, when you call this function. I don't have the entire code to understand what you're doing, but i guess this will work for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Promise.all()`. But the 1st request has to complete before you can kick off the next two (which can run in parallel):

```js
try {
  const login = await sa_login(req)

  const [ userInfo, courseInfo ] = await Promise.all([
     sa_getUserInfo(login),
     sa_getCourseInfo(login)
  ]);

  // do something useful with userInfo and courseInfo here

} catch (err) {

  return return ctx.sendError('400',err);

}
```